# New field in rewards points Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, reward-system

I want to add new field "Point Description" in Rewards points, I am using Magento 1.9.

I have check all the files and trying to debug the code but i am not getting that file from where its generate the form and save the data in to database.

if anyone have idea, please guide me how can i add new field in rewards points

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default Reward Points (Module Enterprise_Reward) are only available in **Magento EE** (Enterprise Edition). Magento 1.9 is a version of Magento CE not Enterprise.

Specify if you are using Magento EE or a custom Extension/Setup

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/marketing/reward-point-configuration.html

Comment: thanks for reply, i am using Magento CE version 1.9.2.4 for rewards points using extension

Comment: Then you shold add extension name and vendor to the question.